# C++ Code For Sorting Array of Indexes Ascending and Descending

Tags: c++11

I'm using the following and it seems verbose. I am wondering if it can be shortened and still accomplish the same thing. Please assume that all variables are initialized with relevant values.

```
if (direction < 0) {
    std::stable_sort(ndx, ndx + Rows, [OffsetCol](long lhs, long rhs) {return CompareVariantsDescending(OffsetCol + lhs, OffsetCol + rhs);});   
} else {
    std::stable_sort(ndx, ndx + Rows, [OffsetCol](long lhs, long rhs) {return CompareVariantsAscending(OffsetCol + lhs, OffsetCol + rhs);});
}
```

I thought of adding `direction` to the lambda capture list and making use of it in the lambda body. But it seems to me that this would be inefficient since the decision on which way to sort would be evaluated on every swap, instead of before the sorting begins.

I also thought of the ternary operator version, but that would make for one very long line of code.

Is there another option?

Comment: I would say its not really that verbose. But instead go the other way, and break it up onto more lines for clarity... i.e. prefer clarity to squishing lots into a small number of lines - just my preference.

Comment: I most of the cases I would prefere this kind of code, as I can easier understand what it does. And I also would not squeeze that in one line. What sometimes can improve readability is to locally alias function names: `constexpr auto Descending = CompareVariantsDescending; ... std::stable_sort(ndx, ndx + Rows, [OffsetCol](long lhs, long rhs) {return Descending(OffsetCol + lhs, OffsetCol + rhs);});`, so you clearly see it is about `Descending` and you don'T get distracted by `CompareVariants`. But only if the scope of that alias is short (not more then a few lines).

Comment: If moving `direction` into the lambda body would have a bad impact on performance, cannot be easily said. Branch prediction and compiler optimizations, could result in the same performance if `direction` is const in the given scope, even if you move it into the lambda function.